# Simplify XSD Schema using XQuery

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

We're building an XQuery tool to create documentation for XSD Schemas (specifically UBL 2.1 Schemas).

In order to do that, we need to simplify schemas built with extensive use of element references and complex types, to be inline definitions.

So an element like this:

```
   <xsd:element name="Order" type="OrderType"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="OrderType">
      <xsd:sequence>
         ...
         <xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
         ...
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
    ...
   (in another file)
   <xsd:element name="UBLVersionID" type="UBLVersionIDType"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="UBLVersionIDType">
      <xsd:simpleContent>
         <xsd:extension base="xsd:string"/> 
      </xsd:simpleContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

Should be converted to:

```
    <xsd:element name="Order">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            ...
            <xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xsd:complexType name="UBLVersionIDType">
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                   <xsd:extension base="xsd:string"/> 
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
            ...
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>    </xsd:element>
```

Taking in account that some elements and types are defined in imported schemas.

Is there a known method to get this with XQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: Do bear in mind that the target form you show is not a legal XSD schema document.  If the only consumer of the output is your documentation software, this won't be an issue.  But if you want to use the inlined ('simplified'?  not really) form to validate (if only for testing to make sure it's accepting and rejecting the same documents as the original), those 'ref' attributes will need to change to 'name' attributes.  (Hmm.  But given the presence of imports, you cannot define the schema in a single schema document (xsd:schema element) in any case.  So maybe it's not an issue.)

Comment: You're right. My interest is to convert a set of schema files (in this case UBL) into a single file totally inlined.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it useful to process the schemas into Saxon's SCM format, which is essentially an XML representation of the XSD schema components in normalized form. You can generate this form using

```
java com.saxonica.Validate -xsd:schema.xsd -scmout:schema.scm
```

The documentation for the SCM format is basically the schema component documentation in the W3C spec.

The format does the opposite of what you are asking for: all components are "out of line", accessed by following references. But it's highly uniform, and avoids all the complexities of managing includes, imports, namespaces, and QNames.

Comment: Any chance to see it on Saxon-HE? (Just til my piggybank get enough money to purchase full Saxon)  ;-)

Comment: Saxon-HE does not include any schema processing capability. Sorry if you can't afford it; we try to make the price affordable while still bringing in enough revenue to fund development of both the commercial and open source products, but there will always be some people who want a feature but can't justify the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a "known method", by which I assume you mean something out of the box or pre-built.

You would effectively need to write a custom transformation, which you could do in either XQuery or XSLT. In XQuery, this is basically a recursive descent and you can find examples here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Transformation_idioms

However as @michael-kay points out, you will have to also write code to process imports and includes. So perhaps pre-processing to the SCM format first (before you do your inlining) is a good idea, of course you will then also need to write a transform to go from SCM back to schema...

Comment: This is the approach I've been using, but I'm having trouble with infinite recursion. Do you have any good XQuery debugger to suggest?

Comment: If you are using Saxon, then there is a pretty decent debugger built into the Oxygen IDE.

Comment: Take a look at the function parse-level() in xsd2json.xqy in the project at https://github.com/lcahlander/xsd2json.git . It handles the infinite recursion problem.